# add git webhook through a script

Tags: git, git-webhooks

Is it possible to add a webhook through a script? Usually, I go to hubricator site and give org/repo details and it creates a webhook for phabricator instance for me so that when some one does checkin, a phabricator review is generated. Can I create a similar webhook using a script?

Answer (score 0):

This would generally be possible if the web service used (hubricator) exposes a public REST API.

Then you could, from a script, call that api (with `curl` for instance) in order to trigger the creation of a webhook for phabricator.
But if there is no API, using a script might not be possible (or at least straightforward)